# HTML Table positioning and column spacing

Tags: html, html-table

In the "table style" portion of my code, is there a way for me to adjust the space between the columns in a table? Also, what attribute should I put in to make sure the tables position is aligned completely to the left and top?

```
<table style="width: 960px; height: 81px;" border="0">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For current and future compatibility use CSS:

```
// cellspacing
table { border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 5px; }
```

To make sure the table is aligned to the left and top, remove any top and left margins. You might also want to change the positioning (position:relative or position:absolute) based on where the table need to exist.

Ref: [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse) | [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-spacing)

Answer (score 0):

`cellpadding` controls the gaps inside cells and `cellspacing` controls the space between them.

```
<table style="width: 960px; height: 81px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

As for alignment, you control this within table cells:

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
```

Comment: I'm using a two column table and i'm only wanting to have space in between the middle of the first and second column. I want to avoid having space on the ends of the table. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Tables do not have that level of control. Consider using a styles unordered list instead. You will have to put a border on the UL and a left or right border in one of the content elements. http://mattdanner.net/two-column-lists-using-html/

Answer (score -1):

you can try with cellspacing property in order to create space